# How to add an entity to a solution with javascript using Web Api action AddSolutionComponent?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

I want to add a custom entity to a custom solution in Dynamics CRM using javascript. 
I've done some research and it turns out that it probably can be be done with Actions. 
`AddSolutionComponent` should do the job, but I'm probably getting something wrong since I'm getting error `400 Request message has unresolved parameters`.

The entity and the solution I am passing in the parameters are both created with javascript, and can found them both in the crm.

```
function associateEntityToSolution(entityId, solutionUniqueName, newSolutionId){

  var param = { 
      'ComponentId': entityId , // newly created entity id 
      'ComponentType':1, // entity type
      'SolutionUniqueName':solutionUniqueName,  //newly created solution id
      'AddRequiredComponents':false,
      'IncludedComponentSettingsValues':null
  };

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/solutions("+newSolutionId+")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddSolutionComponent", true);
  req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
  req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
  req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
          req.onreadystatechange = null;
          if (this.status === 204) {
              var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
              var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
              var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
              var newEntityId = matches[1];
              associateEntityToSolution(newEntityId,entityUniqueName);
          } else {
              window.parent.opener.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
          }
      }
  };
  req.send(JSON.stringify(param));
}
```

Am I missing something in the code?
Are there any other solution to get the job done with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of changes:

1. Commented this line `associateEntityToSolution(newEntityId,entityUniqueName);` as I would guess this may go in loop.
2. Put the solution name not the solution id in param line `'SolutionUniqueName':solutionUniqueName,`

[image]

3. Changed this line `req.open("POST", window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.2/solutions("+newSolutionId+")/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AddSolutionComponent", true);`
    to the correct Action web api call like this:  `req.open("POST", window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/AddSolutionComponent", true);`

-

```
function associateEntityToSolution(entityId, solutionUniqueName, newSolutionId){

  var param = { 
      'ComponentId': entityId , // newly created entity id 
      'ComponentType':1, // entity type
      'SolutionUniqueName':solutionUniqueName,  // solution name (without spaces)
      'AddRequiredComponents':false,
      'IncludedComponentSettingsValues':null
  };

  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  req.open("POST", window.parent.opener.Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.1/AddSolutionComponent", true);
  req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
  req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
  req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
          req.onreadystatechange = null;
          if (this.status === 204) {
              var uri = this.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");
              var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
              var matches = regExp.exec(uri);
              var newEntityId = matches[1];
              //associateEntityToSolution(newEntityId,entityUniqueName);
          } else {
              window.parent.opener.Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
          }
      }
  };
  req.send(JSON.stringify(param));
}
```

I tested this in CRM REST Builder.

Comment: Your solution worked well. The problem was in the  req.open() you told me to change. 
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

URL:

`POST [Your Org]/api/data/v9.0/AddSolutionComponent`

Body:

```
{
    "ComponentId" : "YourComponentGuid",
    "ComponentType" : "YourComponentType", 
    "SolutionUniqueName" : "YourSolutionUniqueName",
    "AddRequiredComponents" : "false", //false or true
    "DoNotIncludeSubcomponents" : "true" //false or true
}
```

ComponentId can be retrieved by doing a GET request to `[Your Org]/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='YourEntityLogicalName')?$select=MetadataId`

Search for available component types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/web-api/solutioncomponent?view=dynamics-ce-odata-9)